# How I can track youtube video shares on facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, youtube

I have used graph.facebook.com to know number of shares of specific URL which it shows easily, but whenever I use a youtube video link such as:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO7cySkUiEE
```

It shows:

```
    {
   "id": "http://www.youtube.com/watch",
   "shares": 2556632,
   "comments": 7
    }
```

which in fact shows for this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch.

How can I resolve this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Server thinks you are sending parameter "v=qO7cySkUiEE" to him as a GET request.
Change question mark in the link to "%3f" (no quotes), it should work.